# Mongodb : Query to list records that have at least 5 fields not equal to null or " " or records with more the 4 'X' s

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with 5 fields:

Chocolate, Biscuits, Wafers, Truffles , Mints

The values for each field is either X, null, or " "

[image: Sample data]

I am trying to list all the records that have at least 4 'X'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This input:

```
var r = [
{store: "A", chocolate:"X", biscuits:"X", wafers: "X", truffles:"X", mints:"X"},
{store: "B", chocolate:null, biscuits:"", wafers: "X", truffles:"X", mints:"X"},
{store: "C", chocolate:null, biscuits:"", wafers: "", truffles:"X", mints:"X"},
{store: "D", chocolate:"X", biscuits:"", wafers: "X", truffles:"X", mints:"X"}
         ];

db.foo.insert(r);
```

will yield the desired result.  `$reduce` is a powerful array-oriented function.  In the use case below, we are saying "for item in the list of fields, if it equals X, add 1 else add 0; when done, N is the result."

```
db.foo.aggregate([
{$addFields: {N: {$reduce: {
                input: ["$chocolate","$biscuits","$wafers","$truffles","$mints"],
                initialValue: 0,
                in: {$sum: [ "$$value", {"$cond":[ {"$eq": ["$$this","X"]}, 1, 0]} ]}
            }}
    }}
,{$match: {"N": {$gte:4} }}
                    ]);

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dda931f76e431f9c9169859"),
    "store" : "A",
    "chocolate" : "X",
    "biscuits" : "X",
    "wafers" : "X",
    "truffles" : "X",
    "mints" : "X",
    "N" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dda931f76e431f9c916985c"),
    "store" : "D",
    "chocolate" : "X",
    "biscuits" : "",
    "wafers" : "X",
    "truffles" : "X",
    "mints" : "X",
    "N" : 4
}
```

Comment: Don't be shy to give it an upvote after the accepted answer.   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I arrived in this solution for this query:

```
db.getCollection("stores").aggregate([
{
    $addFields: {
        fieldsToMatch: ["$chocolates", "$biscuits", "$wafers", "$truffles", "$mints"]
    }
},
{
    $unwind: "$fieldsToMatch"
},
{
    $match: {
        fieldsToMatch: "X"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$name",
        count:{$sum:1}
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        count: {
            $gte: 4
        }
    }
}])
```

I'm basically adding all the values to an array "fieldsToMatch", then using the unwind operator to create several records for each element in the array, matching the ones that have it equal to X, grouping and counting by name (or the _id), then finally matching the ones that have at least 4 occurrences.

The only problem with this approach is you are returning only the _ids of the documents matching the criteria, to get the entire documents you will need to either use lookup or query the collection again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This can get a little slow with large collections because it creates a 5X explosion of data before starting to work on it.